Handling Manual ID Assignment for Synchronization with JPA and GenerationType.IDENTITY
I am migrating the functionalities of an old PHP application to an existing Spring Boot application using JPA for data persistence. The Spring application needs to synchronize data from the older PHP one. A significant aspect of this synchronization process involves preserving certain relationships between entities, specifically Many-to-Many and One-to-Many relationships, which depend on the integrity of the primary keys (IDs) of the entities involved.
Each entity in my domain model uses GenerationType.IDENTITY for its primary key, allowing the database to auto-generate unique IDs as soon as the generation of new entries is allowed on the destination system. However, the synchronization process gives me issues: the entities fetched from the old system already contain their IDs, which are essential for maintaining the integrity of the relationships in the new system.
Upon attempting to save these entities to the new database, the GenerationType.IDENTITY strategy causes the database to ignore the manually assigned IDs and generate new ones instead unless an entry already exists with the id in the new database, which is not always the case. This behaviour disrupts the relationships between entities, leading to inconsistencies in the data model.
Since using a direct database dump is not feasible due to substantial differences in the data structures between the old and new applications (thus why I send the data with JSON while exporting to the new application), I am looking for a solution that allows me to manually assign IDs to entities during the synchronization process while still utilizing the benefits of GenerationType.IDENTITY for new entries.
